# SharePoint Hyperlink column do nothing

Tags: 2013

I have a SharePoint list containing hyperlink column. I want to put some value in the column which do not redirect user. I mean it should do nothing when user click on the link. I tried putting # but form doesn't save because it is invalid to put #.

Eventually i want to achieve this through workflow but before that i want to make it work manual.

Comment: What is the date type of the Column? HyperLink? If you are using J Query then try #! and see if that works. But if the Hyperlink column type is not required, you can just use String

Comment: the column type is hyperlink and it required to be hyperlink. The # keyword does not allowed.

Comment: Okay, you can use client side script to disable the hyperlink functionality. In jQuery something along these document.getElementById('Link1').disabled=true;

Comment: I cant use JQuery because same column may contain a URL which need to redirect properly. Can it be achieve through URL format only?

Answer (score 0):

put the following after the link (you may have to use javascript) onclick=return false;